# In C can I declare a constant character array?

Tags: c, arrays, character

I am working on a character string to signify a change in sign. I have had success with the character string that's commented out below, but would prefer a simple if-else statement using constant character arrays UP = "up/0/0" and DOWN = "down".

Does anyone know a simple way to declare such constant values?

```
    char direction[5]; // declares char array to signify sign change    
    if (value - price1 > - 0.005) { // adjusts for noise near 0
        direction = UP;
    }
    else direction = DOWN;

    // update price-change direction string
//      if (value - price1 > - 0.005) { // adjusts for noise near 0
//          direction[0] = 'u';
//          direction[1] = 'p';
//          direction[2] = 00; // set character to null value
//          direction[3] = 00;
//      }
//      
//      int[4] var_name 
//      else {
//          direction[0] = 'd';
//          direction[1] = 'o';
//          direction[2] = 'w';
//          direction[3] = 'n';
//      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not modifying the string later, you could do it like this:

```
const char *direction:
if (value - price1 > - 0.005) { // adjusts for noise near 0
    direction = UP;
}
else
    direction = DOWN;
```

Comment: one thing I should add is that this code is within a loop. So value will change and direction will need to change repeadedly.

Comment: That's fine. You're not editing the contents of the string. You're just reassigning the pointer.

Comment: @Evan, it's fine to say, e.g. `direction = UP; direction = DOWN;` as many times as you want.  You just can't ever say `direction[0] = 'G';` (or write to `direction` in any other way) if you're setting it up like that.

Comment: interesting. so where do I place this code?  within the loop?

Comment: Assuming you're not going to use `direction` after the loop, yes you can place it inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign like that, but you can do:

```
strcpy(direction, UP);

strcpy(direction, DOWN);
```

Obviously, be careful not to overflow your buffer.  If those are the only possible sources, you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using:

```
const char up_string[] = "UP";
const char down_string[] = "DOWN";
char *direction;
direction = (value - price1 > - 0.005) ? up_string : down_string;
```

You could then have direction simply be a pointer to either of those locations (as opposed to using strcpy).